# When is Nodemailer not free?

Tags: licensing, eupl

I was looking into using Nodemailer in an application of mine and was wondering when isn't it free and requires a license.

http://nodemailer.com/about/license/

I have tried reading over the doc but all the legal stuff goes over my head. [On the pricing page they have this](http://nodemailer.com/about/pricing/):

> Nodemailer is available under a more restrictive license without a fee, so you are free to test Nodemailer before actually buying anything.

But don't really list the restrictions that I can find so not sure what they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading their [license](http://ec.europa.eu/idabc/eupl.html) (EUPL 1.1), it's a copyleft license:

> According  to  its  article  5,  the  EUPL  is  also   copyleft    in 
>   order    to    avoid    any    exclusive     appropriation of the
>   software.

FSF [confirms](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#EUPL) that it's a copyleft license incompatible with, but convertible to, GPL.

So, it's a dual-licensed product, and if you don't wish to distribute your software under EUPL or GPL, you need to pay.